# Combination sum ,recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, combinations

I want to recursively find all the unique combinations in an array nums[] where the numbers sums to the given target value.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> solve(int[] nums,int target) {
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    if(nums == null || nums.length == 0) return res;
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    generate(res , new ArrayList<Integer>(),nums,target,0);
    return res;
}
private static void generate(List<List<Integer>> res, ArrayList<Integer> m, int[] nums,int target, int index) {
if(target == 0 ){
    res.add(m);
    return;
}
for(int i=index;i<nums.length ; i++){
    if(nums[i] > target) break;
    else{
        ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(m);
        copy.add(nums[i]);
        generate(res,copy,nums,target - nums[i],i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try this input, for example:

```
nums = {2,3,6,7} and target = 7;
```

I get

```
[[7]]
```

instead of the expected result

```
[[2,2,3],[7]]
```

Comment: Where in your code do you allow for repetitions? And is using the same list element multiple times within the intention of the task?

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
"generate(res,copy,nums,target - nums[i],i+1);"
```

has problem.

Maybe try to replace i+1 to i

Answer (score 0):

You allow only one instance of each value in **nums**.  You need one of two solutions:

1. Don't automatically increment **i** in your recursion; let the next call pick up with the same value.
2. Use an inner loop to test all possibilities in the range 1 through target//nums.  In the given test case, you need to try 1 and 2 threes; and later 1, 2, and 3 twos.  Change the target to 12, and you'll see a distinct effect of this change, including the following low-value solutions:

   3 3 2 2 2
   3 3 3 3

... in which you have to try with both 2 and 4 threes.  1 and 3 threes will fail to find a smaller solution.